# Debug or release build on staging

Tags: debugging, staging

Obviously staging environment should be an exact copy of production environment. In that sense it is expected to have release built libraries.

But... It's still just a staging server and it makes our lives a lot easier if we could just attach to remote process and see the state of variables. I am not advocating installation of VS on staging nor any other kind of contamination.

Both approaches have pros and cons. I am curious about your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I view the idea of attaching debuggers to servers like staging to be due to a lack of proper logging, error handling, or defensive coding in general. If code is being deployed to staging where problems can't be diagnosed at all, then code is also being deployed to prod where problems can't be diagnosed at all. Instead, from Server-side code, you can write to the ULS log.

Comment: That's all fine and that's how it should be. However, the reality is that the management wants to have everything done yesterday. This causes developers to loose good coding practices. One of those is proper logging.